# Controls not showing on HTML5 Video when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video that I wish to display on my webpage, everything is working except the controls are not showing up. I had an issue with displaying the video in my desired width and height so I used a little javascript hack to make it so. The autoplay attribute works but when applying the controls attribute it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Here is my HTML

```
  <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="1300">
     <video id="video" controls>
       <source src="videos/Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
  </canvas>
```

and the Javascript

```
function updateVideo( ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
    var ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    var myVideo = document.getElementById( 'video' );
    ctx.drawImage( myVideo, 0, 0, 1300, 500 );

}

setInterval ( updateVideo, 24 );
```

Comment: Seems your problem is the `<canvas>` container, why are u wrapping the video in the canvas? and why `setInterval`? Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hb7hjquj/

Comment: The reason for the canvas is so I can adjust the aspect ratio of the video so it can be 1300, 500 rather then the native. As I said i have used this as a hack and I am aware that it works without the canvas feature, There is no way to adjust the video to 1300 x 500 without using this. Well atleast not that I have found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having by placing a canvas over the video is blocking the built in html video controls. My suggestion is to implement your own video controls (play, pause, volume, seeker, etc.) using html and javascript calling the video API. You can probably even make it prettier then the ugly built in controls. Your controls can be contained in a layer above the overlaid canvas, and thus the video will be shown, above it the overlay and above it your control set.

You can read a little about implementing your own controls [here](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/04/14/building-a-better-html5-video-player-with-glow/) or [here](http://htmlstack.com/custom2/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It worked :) I added my own button and access the API

Comment: Glad to help you out :)